# WARNING: No file found for: /sign

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to run the App Engine Tutorial available on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingjsps . As asked by the tutorial, I have mapped the new servlet SignGuestbookServlet.java to the url-pattern "/sign" in web.xml but when I try to access the resource on localhost:8888/sign, I get a 404 error.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sign</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

SignGuestbookServlet.java:

```
package guestbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SignGuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SignGuestbookServlet.class.getName());

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
 resp.getWriter().println("Hello");
    /*UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();


    String content = req.getParameter("content");
    if (content == null) {
        content = "(No greeting)";
    }
    if (user != null) {
        log.info("Greeting posted by user " + user.getNickname() + ": " + content);
    } else {
        log.info("Greeting posted anonymously: " + content);
    }
    resp.sendRedirect("/guestbook.jsp");
    */
}
}
```

Any reason as to why this is happening? Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.: I am using the get method to send data from the form so I have used the doGet() instead of doPost().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Java code. The problem is that there are erroneous (extra) entries in your `web.xml` due to which you start the Local Development Server, there is an error and hence the context is not initialized correctly. As a result, though the server is running, you get an error when you try to access the /sign endpoint.

To fix the problem, do the following :

Currently your `web.xml` is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/sign</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Remove the entries for :

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/guestbook</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your final `web.xml` should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/sign</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Save your `web.xml`. Stop the Local Server. Start the Local Server again. And all should be fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I stopped the local server and started it again. But I guess that didn't work properly. Once I restarted my system the server was forced to start again and then showed me the correct output. And there are two servlets in my code so the web.xml need not be modified.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your Servlet class and the fully qualified name in your web.xml does NOT match. Your servlet class name is `SignGuestbookServlet`

```
public class SignGuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet
```

but in your web.xml it is specified as `GuestbookServlet`

```
<servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
```

Update your web.xml with the right servlet class name as mentioned here

```
<servlet-class>guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: There are two servlets in my code: one is GuestbookServlet and the other is SignGuestbookServlet.

Comment: @Neha Your servlet-mappings are not correct. You have used the same name for both the servlets.